# Replace function arguments name by local variables in Python

Tags: python, function

I want to have the function like the following

```
unit = "days"
datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(unit = 1)
```

Where in the `unit` could be days, hours, and minutes etc., which may be changed according to the the time shift unit.

Is there any way to do it in a fast way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give keyword arguments using a dictionary as follows:

```
args = {'days':1}
datetime.timedelta(**args)
```